# Why does Boolean modifier cause unexpected results when parenting is involved?

Tags: modifiers

I have two objects in a scene: a sphere and a cube, where the sphere is parented to the cube

On the cube I have added a Boolean difference modifier and the sphere is the object that cuts into the cube. However, the **location where the sphere cuts in the cube** is not the same a the **original location of the sphere**.

See following:
[image]

I recalculated the normals of both the sphere and cube, but it does not solve the problem.

The file:
[image]

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that the sphere is parented to the cube. I've reproduced your setup and, on my computer, it also appears quite "glitchy". If you select the sphere, hit "G", then discard the translation with "Esc", does the cut get recalculated to its intended position (as it does on mine)?

Comment: My thought was the parenting as well, but I wasn't sure. Yeah it's glitchy when I move the sphere and hitting escape results indeed in the expected cut. But if select the cube and enter "Edit Mode" and back to "Object Mode" the cut goes back

Comment: Hmm, then we're either in a different situation or I don't quite get what behaviour you're observing. As far as I've reproduced it, the problem is easily solved because starting any operation then dismissing it with "esc" reverts the modifier to a normal state where it stays stable ever since. If this isn't the same for you, I'm unfortunately not able to help. Maybe if you could edit your question and add a Blend file through Blend exchange we can look more directly at your issue.

Comment: Btw, very nice remark about that the sphere is parented to the cube! I forgot to mention it in my question :p

Comment: ALT + "P" clear the parent keeping transformation. CTRL + "A" to apply scale to both objects (one at a time in Object Mode). The Boolean Modifier should work.

Comment: @Dontwalk I would like to keep the parenting, is there a way to parent and use the Boolean modifier?

Comment: Preform the above and re-Parent before applying the Boolean Modifier.

Comment: I have noticed that you are parenting to vertex. Parenting to object still gives some visualisation glitch, but they don't affect the actual object. If your goal allows you to choose between parent to vertex and parent to object, I'd suggest switching to the latter, as a workaround

Comment: but sometimes the result is just a ring instead of a crater and when I have multiple (identical) spheres, it works for some of the spheres while for some it doesn't